# How to do following View using SVG

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am new in UI i want to Build UI like this can any one suggest me is their any Jquery plugin. When user drag image then that part will be active in mobile like below

[image]

Ref: http://urban-walks.com/#map

Comment: There's no SVG on the reference page. Just two version of the map in .jpg: http://urban-walks.com/static/img/slider/map/map-light_3000.jpg and http://urban-walks.com/static/img/slider/map/map-dark_3000.jpg - dark version is inside a large div, and the light version inside the iphone. Then both are repositioned when the user drags the background.

Comment: @pawel But how to repositioned the image? can you share example